# Nothing imported with mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am trying to familiarize with mysql and specifically import .csv data. I tried with the data import wizard of the workbench without particularly problems. Nonetheless, since I have to import a quite large database (roughly 3 GB), the import wizard does not work. Surfing on the net, the best choice seems to be the use of mysqlimport. Therefore, I tried to practicing with it by using a very small data sample. Unfortunately, I am not able to upload any kind of data in this way.

Assume I want to create a table called 'import_prova' with four columns and a bunch of rows within a database named 'prova'. Something like the following one:

```
+------+--------+----------+--------+
| id   | field1 | field2   | field3 |
+------+--------+----------+--------+
|    1 |     10 | pippo    | 2      |
|    2 |     20 | pippo    | 2      |
|    3 |     30 | pluto    | 3      |
|    4 |     15 | paperino |        |
+------+--------+----------+--------+
```

In order to do so from the WindowsPowerShell (where I have accessed as administrator) I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE import_prova (
id INT NOT NULL,
field1 INT NULL,
field2 TEXT NULL,
field3 TEXT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I tried to import the data even with 'LOAD DATA LOCAL ...', but without success. Then, I tried with mysqlimport with the following line code:

```sh
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-escaped-by='' --fields-terminated-by='\t' --verbose --local -u root -p --columns='id,field1,field2,field3' prova 'C:/Users/[rest-of-the-path]/import_prova.csv'
```

However, what I get is the following output:

```
Connecting to localhost
Selecting database prova
Loading data from LOCAL file: C:/Users/[rest-of-the-path]/import_prova.csv into import_prova
prova.import_prova: Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
Disconnecting from localhost
```

Honestly, I tried several time. For sure I am missing something stupid. I have been stuck for days with this (silly) issue, I hope someone could kindly help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have two `--fields-terminated-by` options. Does the file use comma or tab as the field terminator?

Comment: Thank you so much. I forget it. Actually, the error was not only in the repeated `--fields-terminated-by` but also in the missing `--lines-terminated-by='\r'` 
However, I do not know why now the table has a first row numbered with 0 in the first column, followed by three NULL values. Something like this:

`|  0 |   NULL | NULL     | NULL   |`